# Turn url path into query string while keeping the old query string with .htaccess

Tags: .htaccess, url, redirect, query-string

Basically, using .htaccess, I want to go from this url:

`localhost/data/image.jpg?size=400`

to this url:

`localhost/image.php?file=data/image.jpg&size=400`

I tried variant things from what the internet could give me, but nothing seemed to match my purpose.

I have very litle knowledges of how to use .htaccess, which makes understanding the various answers online a bit difficult.

**EDIT:** I have tried this, which does part of the redirection

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule data/(.*) /image.php?file=data/$1 [PT]
```

Except it deletes the  `?size=400`, which I do not want.

And when I try to type

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule data/(.*)?(.*) /image.php?file=data/$1&size=$2 [PT]
```

It appears the output is `localhost/image.php?file=data/image.png%26size=`, which just won't work.

Also, I would like to be able to go further than just data/ later on

Comment: Welcome to SO, please do add your htaccess file in your question which you have tried, thank you.

Comment: Can you try something like this, `RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^size=` and `RewriteRule ^data/(.*) image.php?file=data/$1 [L,QSA]` The condition for the query string could be made more specific, if needed - or maybe it could be left out completely, if you wanted to rewrite `/data/image.jpg` as well. The QSA flag merges the original query string with the new one.

Comment: @CBroe This has solved it ! Thank you! You can write it as an actual answer, and I will validate it :D - And if I want to use something else than data/, I can simply write `RewriteRule ^(.*) image.php?file=$1 [L,QSA]`

Comment: In that case you’d have to be careful, because the pattern `^(.*)` would also match on `image.php`, so this can easily create a loop.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Personally, I try and avoid using `%{THE_REQUEST}`, when there’s alternatives available. The path can be matched by the RewriteRule here, so the RewriteCond can look at the query string contents instead directly.

```
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^size=
RewriteRule ^data/(.*) image.php?file=data/$1 [L,QSA]
```

The `QSA` flag makes mod_rewrite merge the query string you are creating, with the original one.

The condition for the query string could be made more precise (or less) - depending on your specific needs. Right now, it just checks that the query string starts with `size=`, and not more.

If you wanted to redirect *all* `/data/image.jpg` requests, no matter whether they have a query string or not, and if they have one, no matter what it contains - then the RewriteCond could just be removed completely. If a query string existed, it will be merged via the `QSA` flag, if not, then it will consist *only* of your `file` parameter.

Answer (score 0):

With your shown samples, could you please try following.
Please clear your browser cache before testing your URLs.

```
RewriteEngine ON
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} \s/data/(image\.jpg)?(size=\d+)\s [NC]
RewriteRule ^ image.php?file=data/%1&size=%2 [L]
```

Comment: Am I supposed to write something instead of %{THE_REQUEST} ?

Comment: @TotoShampoin, yeah we should use it as its shown, let me know how it goes.

Comment: I don't know what to put instead of %{THE_REQUEST}, but it apparently doesn't work with %{REQUEST_URI}, nor with %{QUERY_STRING}... I may be missing something here.

Comment: @TotoShampoin, this is tested in my local, could you please do let me know which sample URL you are hitting here?

Comment: Well, on the debugging .htaccess websites, it says that in both case, the RewriteCond on line 2 didn't match the query ( localhost/image.jpg?size=400 )

Comment: @TotoShampoin, Sorry to say but those sites are not good, they give errors on correct codes too, I had tested this on local, kindly do apply them on your htaccess file and clear cache then try your URL, let me know how it goes cheers.

Comment: Well, I also tried it on my local and it didn't seem to work... But CBroe has solved the problem, so thanks to all of you guys for your help :)

Comment: @TotoShampoin, sure, I have added `data` in path, could you please do check it once and let me know if this helps you?